# Limit RANGE with condition in Window function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, window-functions, median, moving-average

Take an example I have the following transaction table, with transaction values of each department for each trimester.

```
    TransactionID  | Department | Trimester | Year | Value | Moving Avg
    1              | Dep1       |     T1    | 2014 |   13  |
    2              | Dep1       |     T1    | 2014 |   43  |
    3              | Dep1       |     T2    | 2014 |   36  |

   300             | Dep1            T1 |    2017 |   28  |
   301             | Dep2            T1 |    2014 |   24  |
```

I would like to calculate moving average for each transaction from the same department, taking the window as from the 6 trimesters to 2 trimesters before the current line's trimester. Example for transaction 300 in T1 2017, I'd like to have the average of transaction values for Dep1 from T1-2015 to T2-2016.

How can I achieve this with sliding window function in SQL Server 2014. My thought is that I should use something like

```
SELECT 
AVG(VALUES) OVER 
(PARTITION BY DEPARTMENT ORDER BY TRIMESTER, 
YEAR RANGE [Take the range from previous 6 to 2 trimesters])
```

How would we define the `RANGE` clause. I suppose I could not use `ROWS` due to the number of rows for the window is unknown.

The same question for median. How would we rewrite for calculating the median instead of mean ?

Comment: please add expected result in formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt

Comment: may be useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43345402/sql-server-how-to-do-3-months-partition/43346202#43346202